# Fresh Ubuntu 13.10 install has slow unity animations with Haswell integrated graphics

Tags: unity

I got a new PC with an i5-4570 that has an HD4600 integrated graphics card. (It also came with a discrete Radeon 7670 card which I disabled in the BIOS because it seem it is easier to get along with Intel drivers these days ??).

I did a fresh install but some unity animations are slow and stutter. For example Alt+Tab switching or Super+s window spread animation etc..

It seems everything is set up correctly but these stuttering animations are kind of annoying. Here are some outputs :

```
~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Desktop 
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 9.2.1

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes


~$ glxgears
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
303 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.546 FPS
301 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.033 FPS
301 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.033 FPS
```